Should we rename Pokemon TCGP to Pokemon TCG Pocket?
Recently a new Pokemon game was released named "Pokemon Trading Card Game Pocket". There are currently 2 questions related, tagged as pokemon-tcgp
I get that Trading Card Game is ofted written as TCG and it's common use, but Pocket has nothing to do with the acronym.
So, can we use a better tag? Something like pokemon-tcg-pocket

Given how we have pokemon-tcg-online and pokemon-tcg-gbc, it would make sense to have pokemon-tcg-pocket

Seems reasonable. I went ahead and created the new tag, and retagged the 2 questions to use it. I did not make the other tag a synonym as it didn't seem particularly needed. So, provided no questions are using it in about 10 hours from this post, the old tag should disappear by itself. I copied over the tag info and made a generic tag wiki as well.

Great, thank you!
